# The database backup in postgresql is five times larger than the database itself

Tags: postgresql, backup

My English is bad and I used a translator. I am doing backup using:

```
pg_dump -p 5432 db> backup.sql
```

At the moment, the weight of the backup reaches 4GB, and continues to grow more and more. At the same time, the database itself weighs only 700MB. I think that it should not be so, how can you optimize the creation of a backup and reduce its weight?

Comment: How are you measuring the size of the database and the file? Are you sure you are dumping the same database you are measuring in the cluster? Also note you are doing an uncompressed plain text dump of the database.

Answer (score 1):

It is very unusual for a dump to be larger than the database; usually that means that you have `bytea` columns or large objects in there. But even with these I could not explain a factor of five.

Without understanding the cause, the solution is probably to use a compressed custom format dump:

```sh
pg_dump -F c -p 5432 -f backup.sql db
```